# MS Teams DevOps Connection "you have no associated Azure DevOps organizations"

Tags: azure, azure-devops, connection, microsoft-teams

I have an Azure Organization and Devops Project assigned to my user with all the permissions setup to same as the Organiazation Owner (same email AD domain).

When I launch Azure Devops App within MS Teams, I click to Set up and it says "Sorry, you have no associated Azure DevOps organizations".  The Organization Owner has no problem and can see the Option.  I have rebooted, re-logged-in etc etc, checked every conceivable permission in MS Teams, OFfice 365 Admin, dev.azure.com Organization level... it still does not show the Organization in Teams.

Yet I can see the Devops Board which the Azure Devops Organization owner setup on Teams as a Tab.

Is there something I'm missing?  Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you again for the feedback.  The problem was that I had created another Azure account with my email address.  I deleted the Organization but the Azure Devops add-in for MS Teams still picked the deleted Organisation as my primary Azure account despite me being assigned as an Admin to another Azure Devops Organisation and Project.  It took about a week for my legacy credentials to expire and eventually I could connect to the new Azure Devops organisation.

I also received some excellent links to manage and support MS Teams integration with Devops so am posting it here in case anyone else finds it useful...

The MS teams extension for Azure DevOps has been deprecated and we suggest you to use the MS Teams apps for Azure DevOps.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/integrations/microsoft-teams?view=azure-devops
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/integrations/boards-teams?view=azure-devops
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/integrations/repos-teams?view=azure-devops

You could refer the below document which mentions the multi tenant feature of the MS teams app for Azure DevOps. This could help you to connect to all the organizations from different client AADs.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/integrations/microsoft-teams?view=azure-devops#multi-tenant-support

Answer (score 0):

Users need to be granted with at least stakeholders access at the DevOps organization level ( not just the project ). Tell the owner to add them in there.

Check this out for further references: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/access-levels?view=azure-devops#stakeholder-access

Comment: Sure, let me know how that works. If that resolves your issue, please upvote my answer and proceed closing the question marking it as resolved. Good luck!

Comment: Sadly not.   I think there is an authentication problem on my Teams account.  I am setup with Devops Organization BASIC access which i gather is higher than STAKEHOLDER.  It's very puzzling and such a shame since was looking forward to using DevOps Server with Teams.  

I'm not quite on the same page yet as the comment I get with the "Sorry, you have no associated Azure DevOps organizations."... and then you get "Microsoft Teams and Azure DevOps make collaborating on software projects easy and fun" :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the prerequisites in this [link](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/teams/#prerequisites) and check whether your account and organization meet the prerequisites:

- You should have Office365 account in order to integrate Azure DevOps
  Services with Microsoft Teams.
- Only Azure DevOps organizations in the same organization (AAD tenant)
  can be used to integrate with your Microsoft Teams account.

In addition, here is a [case](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/798096/unable-to-use-azure-devops-apps-for-ms-teams-when.html) you can refer to.